# IClientApiService is null if server role is CM

Tags: exm

We are adding contact on Email subscription.

```
IClientApiService _clientApiService = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<IClientApiService>();
_clientApiService.UpdateListSubscription(new UpdateListSubscriptionMessage()
{
    ListSubscribeOperation = ListSubscribeOperation.Subscribe,
    ContactIdentifier = contact.Identifiers.FirstOrDefault(),
    MessageId = Guid.Parse(id),
    ManagerRootId = Guid.Parse(managerRootId),
    RequireSubscriptionConfirmation = true,
 });
```

However, this code is working fine on Standalone role but when we are using this code on CM role then we are getting `null` in `_clientApiService` and it is throwing an error.

I am using Sitecore version 9.1.1.

Comment: Hi, it must be because the service is defined in Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cd.dll that does not exist on your CM.

Comment: I have set CM role in web.config at my local and getting the same issue. It is working fine for standalone at my local. Is there any setting at local for Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cd.dll for CM role ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because, the registration of `IClientApiService` is in the `\App_Config\Sitecore\EmailExperience\Sitecore.EmailExperience.ContentDelivery.config` file which has a role constraint - `role:require="Standalone or ContentDelivery"`.
The following lines are responsible to register the `IClientApiService` (and some others):

```
<services>
    <!-- Configurator used by EXM to register required services -->
    <configurator type= "Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cd.DependencyInjection.CustomServiceConfigurator, Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cd"/>
</services>
```

If you need this on CM, you need to patch this configuration by using the `ContentManagement` role.

Comment: One question here , Do I need to patch Sitecore.EmailExperience.ContentDelivery.config file on same path `\App_Config\Sitecore\EmailExperience\` ?

Comment: No, you should able to patch in the `\App_Config\Include` folder.